# Base template for style chunk templates

Tags: java, android, css, chunk-templates

I try implementing a base template for CSS style for all my templates.

I read documentation and found info about {% super %} use, but I don't understand how to use it.

Do you have an experience of use it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the site guidelines. When you created your account here, it was suggested that you take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) guidelines. Please do so, especially [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What kinds of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), before asking your next question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is reuse some common template code, you have a number of options.

`{% super %}` is really just for override layers, which you would only use if you had finished the layout for an entire app and wanted to maintain another version with slightly different content or layout.

1. You could have all templates include a header that pulls in a common css file (or keep it super-simple and define a few css classes here, using `<style>...</style>` tags instead of the `<link rel>`).

header.chtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$base_url}/css/common.css" />
 </head>
```

about.chtml

```
{.include header}
...
```

2. Or you could create a template to use as a "shell" macro and exec it from other pages.

shell.chtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>{$page_title}</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$base_url}/css/common.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  {$body}
 </body>
</html>
```

about.chtml

```
{% exec shell %}
{$page_title=About Us}

{$body=}
<div>
...
</div>
{=}

{% endexec %}
```